# How to use Openvpn and system VPN(PPTP) at the same time?

Tags: openvpn

I need to connect VPN using Mac's system(PPTP) and use Openvpn to connect to my private servers. But it seems that I can't connect both of them at the same time.

Is there any way to solve this? For example, change the config of my openvpn(I use Tunnelblick)

Comment: I think you should think of connection sharing between two. But Ive seen somewhere that you will be have a DNS problem. at your own risk! ;)

Comment: @UltraDEVV Do you know how to do this?